# i can' t understand how JSON works on this website

Tags: python, json, web-scraping

I have 2 questions:

1. My goal is to scrape live data from this example website(or other live basketball match):

https://www.oddsportal.com/basketball/greece/greek-cup/promitheas-panathinaikos-MTkEXywD/inplay-odds/#over-under;1

When I open development tools and browse JSON from request:

https://fb.oddsportal.com/feed/live/1-3-zVIgebsh-2-1-yjc50.dat?_=1573397634508

I saw more data but I don't know what to do with that.
For example on the previous page:

https://www.oddsportal.com/inplay-odds/live-now/basketball/

I have similar table, but I managed do get result:

2.24 - 1.58 - Filippos Veroi - AS Karditsas

1.26 - 3.56 - Bayern - Alba Berlin

1.24 - 4.21 - Bayreuth - Basketball Braunschweig

2.2 - 1.75 - Gottingen - Oldenburg

1.01 - 12.43 - Donar Groningen - Rotterdam

by this code:

```
import json
import time
import pprint
import re
import sys

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://fb.oddsportal.com/feed/livegames/live/3/0.dat?_{}".format(int(time.time() * 1000))
headers = {
'User-Agent': 'curl/7.64.0',
'Referer': 'https://www.oddsportal.com/inplay-odds/live-now/basketball/',
}
 page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

 result = re.search("globals.jsonpCallback\('/feed/livegames/live/3/0.dat', (.*)\);", page.text)
 if not result:
   sys.exit("Result not found")   

 #print(result.group(1))
 json_text = result.group(1)
 json_data = json.loads(json_text).get('d')

 soup = BeautifulSoup(json_data.get('text', ''), 'html.parser')

 with open('test.html', 'w+') as f:
   f.write(str(soup))

for m in soup.select('tr[xeid]'):
name = m.find('td', class_='name table-participant').text
#print (len(name))
#ids = m.find_all('td', class_='live odds-nowrp')
xoid, xodd = (s['xoid'].split('-')[-1] for s in m.find_all('td', class_='live odds-nowrp'))
xoid_data = json_data.get('odds', {}).get(xoid)
xodd_data = json_data.get('odds', {}).get(xodd)
if xoid_data is not None:
    xoid_data = xoid_data[1]
if xodd_data is not None:
    xodd_data = xodd_data[1]   
print(u'{} - {} - {}'.format(xoid_data, xodd_data, name))
```

But on the previous page JSON is different. I extracted id from "text" and use "odds" to get data, but here I see  many "odds" which makes me confused.

How JSON works on next page?
How I can get similar result like a previous page?
(for example:

Over/Under +155.5 -  3.06 -  1.31

Over/Under +156.5 -  2.82  - 1.35

Over/Under +157.5  - 2.61  -  1.41

Over/Under +158.5 -  2.43  -  1.47

Over/Under +159.5 -  2.27  -  1.54

Over/Under +160.5 -  2.12  -  1.61

Over/Under +161.5 -  2.00  -  1.67

2. https://www.oddsportal.com/basketball/greece/greek-cup/promitheas-panathinaikos-MTkEXywD/inplay-odds/#over-under;1

I'm intrested in download text like a "1st Quarter 7" (2cm up table).
I quess that answer is here in JSON:

https://fb.oddsportal.com/feed/postmatchscore/3-MTkEXywD-yj837.dat?_=1573399835075

but similar to first question I don't understand how JSON works on this website

thank you in advance for help.

Comment: Please unsure that enough information to answer the question, or learn from an answer, or check an answer's correctness is included *in the question itself*. We want knowledge base entries to remain useful to others even when external site contents change.

Comment: (Also, each SO question should have only one underlying question per; a "question" with two questions within it should be... two separate questions).